# Remove Field name from beginning of the error message in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4

How to remove the model name from the beginning of the error message. while writing custom message for a validation.
My validation is like:

```
validates :phone, presence: {  message: "For security, please enter your <strong> mobile phone number </strong>" }
```

But the o/p: is like:

> Phone For security, please enter your mobile phone number

I want remove the field name ie. phone from the beginning of the error message.
I am using Ruby 2.4 with Rails 5.2 
please guide with correct syntax to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the hash with the errors. Identifying each validation error with their corresponding column, e.g.:

```
{:phone=>["For security, please enter your <strong> mobile phone number </strong>"]}
```

So from there, you can do `errors[:phone].first`. Make sure of selecting the proper error message. As you have only a presence validation, getting the first element is enough, but might vary.

```
foo = User.new
foo.valid? # false
foo.errors
# => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f80d52ff2a8
#  @base=#<User:0x00007f80d52c4bd0 id: nil, phone: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil ...>,
#  @details={:phone=>[{:error=>:blank}]},
#  @messages={:phone=>["For security, please enter your <strong> mobile phone number </strong>"]}>
foo.errors[:phone]
# => ["For security, please enter your <strong> mobile phone number </strong>"]
foo.errors[:phone].first
# => "For security, please enter your <strong> mobile phone number </strong>"
```